# Is there a way to retrieve multiple sensor data in Android

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, sensors

I'm trying to get both accelerometer and orientation data. Currently, I created an AccelerometerManager and OrientationManager. They both do the same thing; implement SensorEventListener and retrieve data from values[] in onSensorChanged() listeners.

Is there an easier way to do this? It seems like having 2 handlers with duplicate code is uneccessary. Is there a way to access a values[] array with the combined accelerometer and orientation data together?

Because of the 2 handlers, I'm also having to do this:

```
    orientationManager = new OrientationManager(this);
    orientationSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    orientationSensorManager.registerListener(orientationManager, 
            orientationSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    accelerometerManager = new AccelerometerManager(this);
    accelerometerSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometerSensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerManager, 
            orientationSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private SensorEventListener mSensorListener;

////


mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            //TODO: get values
        }else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            //TODO: get values
        }
    }
}

mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Comment: By the way, there's no reason why your Activity can't implement SensorEventListener directly, and then you pass "this" as the first argument to registerListener().

Comment: Isn't SensorEventListener an interface? Can you make an instance of an interface? Thanks