# Get multiple sensor data at the same time in Android

Tags: android, sensors

I am now trying to create an app to monitoring the vibration. I use accelerometer to finish the job, when the recorded acceleration exceed certain threshold, I call it a trigger. When there's a trigger, I want to log the acceleration, magnetic field, light level data (from different sensors) at the trigger time to a file.

The problem now is that: I can get data from individual sensor, but couldn't figure out a way how to get the data from multiple sensors at the same time. For example: I can set a sensorlistener to monitoring the change of accelerometer, when I record the acceleration data, can I also get data from other sensors at exactly the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to retrieve multiple sensor data in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343342/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-multiple-sensor-data-in-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do this as follows:

```
private SensorManager manager;
private SensorEventListener listener;

manager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
listener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            ...
        }
        else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

manager.registerListener(listener, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
manager.registerListener(listener, manager.getDefaultSensor(TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Comment: Thanks paritybit, I tried this, but this seems not collecting data at the same time, for example, when there's a sensor event change, it only check whether it is accelerometer or gyroscope. What I want is when the accelerometer change, at the same time, I collect data from accelerometer and gyroscope.

Comment: I don't think they event model works this way. Seems when Android gets the sensor data, it executes the subscribed event listener, and then we get the sensor data out of the event. Not that we can go fetch data at a set point in time from any sensor.

Comment: @GregRandall what if both sensors changed at the same time? What will be logged to `event.values[]`?

Comment: @Chaine The event would fire once for each sensor type. Its up to you store the data and use it.