# Android get sensor data without EventListeners

Tags: android, actionlistener, sensors

I'm obtaining data form an sensor via a listener and if this event is triggered i want to get data form a different sensor(light). I'm using a Listener for the first sensor but I don't want to wait for the next sensor change of the light sensor. So can i pull the sensor data directly?

Comment: Most sensors can only be retrieved via the listener interface. Most sensors also fluctuate rapidly, so you rarely have to wait long. I do not know if there is a trick specific to the ambient light sensor that would allow you to get the current value immediately.

Comment: So what is the best practices to execute code, based on conditions of two sensors? Something like:If sensorvalue1>... and sensorvalue2=... than ...

Comment: I cannot really answer that, as I do not have enough context. If you are dependent upon two sensors, most likely you are going to need to hold onto the data from the last `SensorEvent` for each sensor, so when a `SensorEvent` comes in for one sensor, you have events for both (the new one, plus the last one for the other sensor) in order to run your calculations. Just bear in mind that you want to hold onto the *data* (e.g., `values`) of the `SensorEvent`, not the `SensorEvent` itself, as those objects get recycled.

Comment: I think this guy has a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326429/get-multiple-sensor-data-at-the-same-time-in-android, but no solution. So the best why is to listen for both sensor events and save the values? Does it drain the battery more to listen for more sensors?

Comment: Each sensor that you require to be in operation may contribute to power drain, though how much will vary by sensor and device.