# How to read Android Sensor data only once, when asked for

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sensors, sensormanager

I'm trying to read the accelerometer and/or geomagnetic sensor in a Java android app to determine the device orientation at one point. But the sensor itself doesn't matter, and my question could be applied to any type of sensor you'd like to read, whether it'd be motion, temperature, light, pressure and what not.

I'm seeing everywhere code to setup a "stream" of data from the sensor, with event listeners and the ability to "react" to the data the sensors sends you with callbacks.

That's not what I'm after, and I think it might not be possible to do what I want.

What is want is to read the sensor data once.
Not twice, not for 3 seconds straight, not when the sensor sends me an event.
Turn it on, read it, turn it off.

I just need one reading, when I ask for the reading.
And when I get that reading, I do not need more readings afterwards.

It feels like it should be an easy one line operation once you have sufficient permissions like `anysensor.getCurrentState()`.
But from what I can read around, I only find documentation relying on event listeners from the sensorManager and having to setup a whole class and 5 different event callbacks :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position#sensors-pos-orient

I'm guessing I can do that and try to make it as light as possible, make the eventListeners self-stop on the first reading. But it feels quite tideous and much code for what I need. And also i'm trying to do a really simple task, get the reading, to something about it, and be done with it, and this would require something asynchronous.
So I guess I would have to "pause" the app until I get that first result.

Would that actually be the simplest / only way to do it ?

Comment: what's the problem with the first example on that page?

Comment: it's an asynchronous setup with 5 event listeners, two functions making two pages of code.
My question is "is there a way to read sensor data only once, without event listeners"
Something like `sensor.getcurrentState()` (i made that one up).
One line, maybe 5, not 100.

I do not need anything asynchronous, I do not need continuous data from the sensor.
I thought what I wrote explained this ?

Comment: If there is not otherway than having to do the full setup I would like to know too. But ideally, I wish there was a simpler way to go about reading the sensor only once.

Comment: for real? the first example that you see on that page is probably what you are looking for! `private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
...
// Rotation matrix based on current readings from accelerometer and magnetometer.
val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9);
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelerometerReading, magnetometerReading);

// Express the updated rotation matrix as three orientation angles.
val orientationAngles = FloatArray(3);
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles);`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia thank you for that, I'm sorry I thought you were talking about another piece of code. But I think it's not working. Maybe I'm mistaken but in their example the "..." would be some code missing.
And from what I understand you have to feed data from the sensors as an arguments to `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix( (float[] R, float[] I, float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic)` (**accelerometerReading** and **magnetometerReading** in their example). But they don't show how to get those values except in the examples with eventListeners...

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getRotationMatrix(float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[])

Comment: I did yesterday, before your first comment. Like I said in my latest comment, "getRotationMatrix" needs arguments (accelerometerReading and magnetometerReading as third and fourth parameter). WE have to provide those arguments to the function. The function does not provide us the readings.
Now in order to get the "accelerometerReading" and "magnetometerReading" we need to use the accelerometer and the magnetometer. 
getRotationMatrix is just a tool to help us compute the sensor readings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing a final answer to my question, as I found a solution that fits my specific usecase.

Even though my action was not supposed to be "asynchronous", what I ended up doing was spliting my script so that "job.done();" carries on for the rest of my script, making the "coding" mostly similar to a synchronous script.

For the purpose of sharing, I've striped out most of the things and tried to keep only the interesting part. And I hope it would be enough for anyone trying to do something similar. This is also the shortest way I've found to access the accelerometer's data.

basicaly, the idear is that I have a `switch`, depending on the result I might need the Sensor or I might not need it (kept only two cases to illustrate my point).
when the `case` is `"portrait"` I can keep everything synchronous, and call "job.done();" which will continue the rest of the script.

However, if the `case` is `"auto_landscape"`, I want to use the sensor. As I only need one reading, when the sensors sends its first callback (`onSensorChanged()`) it will unregister itself, and then uses the same `job.done();` method to finish the script.

Here it is :

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

switch(currentMode) {
    case "portrait":
        setRotation(0);
        job.done("Portrait");
        break;

    case "auto_landscape":
        sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {}
            @Override public synchronized void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if (event.values[0] > 0 ) {
                    // landscape right
                    setRotation(1);
                } else {
                    // landscape left
                    setRotation(3);
                }
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorListener);
                job.done("Landscape (auto)");
            }
        };
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST );
        break;
    default:
        job.done("Something is wrong!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read here, it doesn't seem possible to read sensor data without setting up eventListeners.

[Android get sensor data without EventListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599070/android-get-sensor-data-without-eventlisteners)

I'm not closing the question just yet, in case someone can confirm it's the case or otherwise.

If someone would have tips for the best way to integrate this asynchronous step in the middle of a synchronous function, it would be welcome !