# Multiple sensors using event.values as app cannot identify difference

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to display the data from two different sensors and if i comment out the accelerometer data the app will run and show the light sensor data but trying to display the accelerometer data being displayed causes it to crash on launch. if i comment out everything to do with the light sensor i do get the accelerometer data to be shown but they will not be able to be shown at the same time.

the issue being that both sensors use event.values yet at least from my own research this should work although else if gives error in on sensorChanged 
which was how [Get multiple sensor data at the same time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326429/get-multiple-sensor-data-at-the-same-time-in-android) recommended to solve this issue 
any help would be great

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

//System sensor manager
SensorManager sensorManager;
//active sensors
Sensor lightSensor;
Sensor acelSensor;

TextView xText, yText, zText, lightS;


double ax,ay,az;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //initulise veriables
    lightS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lightS);
    xText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xText);
    yText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yText);
    zText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zText);
    //instance of sensor manager

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    //get sensors from sensor manager
    lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    acelSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    //if error
    if (lightSensor == null) { lightS.setText("sensor_error"); }
    if (acelSensor == null) {
        xText.setText("sensor_error");
}}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (lightSensor !=null)
    {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
    if (acelSensor !=null)
    {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, acelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, acelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) ;
        {
            float lux = event.values[0];
            lightS.setText(String.valueOf(lux));
        }
          if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) ;{
            /*ax=event.values[0];
            ay=event.values[1];
            az=event.values[2];*/
            xText.setText("X:   " +  event.values[0]);
            yText.setText("Y:   " + event.values[1]);
            zText.setText("Z:   " + event.values[2]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i presume the program  doesn't know what event value to put in what place  but cannot figure out how to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You are registering your sensors twice, once at onstart(), and again at onresume().

I removed the extra onregistersensor().

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

//System sensor manager
SensorManager sensorManager;
//active sensors
Sensor lightSensor;
Sensor acelSensor;

TextView xText, yText, zText, lightS;

double x;
double y;
double z;
double ax, ay, az;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //initulise veriables
    //       lightS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lightS);
    //       xText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xText);
    //      yText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yText);
    //       zText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zText);
    //instance of sensor manager

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);



}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) ;
    {
        float lux = event.values[0];

        System.out.println("lux " + lux);
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        x = event.values[0] /9.8;
        y = event.values[1] /9.8;
        z = event.values[2] /9.8;

        System.out.println("x: " + x);
        System.out.println("y: " + y);
        System.out.println("z: " + z);


    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}