# Listening to multiple Sensors and updating multiple TextViews with the sensor values on Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I have been working on a mysterious app that allows a user to fetch multiple Sensor Values at the same time and display them on a Listview. However, to my dismay I have never been able to get past fetching Accelerometer Values and that is about it. I have tried multiple ways to register all the available sensors like Gyroscope,Magnetic Field, Orientation etc. None of them retrieve values since Accelerometer takes the priority and gets fired every time. Is there a way to register multiple sensors at the same time and obtain data from them to update the UI.

```
mAccelerometerListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
            //Update UI
            } 
        }
    };

    mGyroscopeListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                //Update Ui

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    mMagnetometerListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                //Update UI
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

if (Config.isSensorPresent(ACCELERATION)) {
        //sendMessageToService(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mAccelerometerListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }
    // Detect whether the device has Gyroscope on it
    if (Config.isSensorPresent(GYROSCOPE)) {
        //sendMessageToService(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mGyroscopeListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }
    // Detect whether the device has Magnetic Field Sensor
    if (Config.isSensorPresent(MAGNETIC_FIELD)) {
        //sendMessageToService(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mMagnetometerListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }
```

This doesn't seem to update all of them at the same time. Heck, it doesn't even fire other sensor types.

Have tried the method suggested at [Is there a way to retrieve multiple sensor data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343342/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-multiple-sensor-data-in-android). Does not work for me.

Comment: Please post full code

Answer (score 2):

I think that line 8 might be your problem. However you can also try the following code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    SensorEventListener{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            Sensor se = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            sm.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, se, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
            Sensor se1 = sm.getDefaultSensor(TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
            sm.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, se1, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
            Sensor se2 = sm.getDefaultSensor(TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
            sm.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, se2, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                 //Update UI        
            }
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
            //UpdateUI
             }
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
            //UpdateUI
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    }
```

This code should work because whenever any of the above three sensor value is changed (almost always) this function(OnSensorChanged()) is called.
If this does not then the problem might be in your updateUI code.

Answer (score 0):

have a single sensor event listener and register all sensor to it , but inside on onSensorChanged() method you can find out which sensor has called it and act accordingly.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)//update gyro
if (event.sensor.getType() == //acclometer)update acc
.
.
.
so on

        }
```