# Android : How to retrieve multiple sensor data and detect changes

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

My activity implements `SensorEventListener`, and I registered my `sensorManager` to the three sensors:

```
// register all the sensors
    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) != null) {
        gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) != null) {
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
```

I have also registered and unregistered the sensor manager in onResume() and onPause().

I have a method saveData which would detect all the sensor changes and write to a file.

I used the method from:[Is there a way to retrieve multiple sensor data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343342/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-multiple-sensor-data-in-android)

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            ax = event.values[0];
            ay = event.values[1];
            az = event.values[2];

        } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            gx = event.values[0];
            gy = event.values[1];
            gz = event.values[2];
        } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            mx = event.values[0];
            my = event.values[1];
            mz = event.values[2];
        }


        content += (currentTime - startTime) + ax + " " + ay + " " + az + " " + mx + " " + my + " " + mz + " " + gx + " " + gy + " " + gz + "\n";
    }

}
```

My file saving method:

```
 try {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream.write(title.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.write(content.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
```

But the problem is that the content variable wouldn't change at all. Is it because all the sensors are changing at the same time? How to actually retrieve the data to content and write to the file?

Comment: I think, you should create separate thread for each sensor and save data in a separate threads and separate files in order to avoid file locking during saving data. You can use this hint to improve your solution.